Tp Link AC 600 Not working
The TP-Link AC600 adapter is recognized by the system as shown by lsusb, and the driver is installed as indicated by dkms status, however the adapter is not functioning properly.


Please post text in the body of the question with cut and past and remove the picture. Pictures can not be searched, sorted and often have bits cut off. Also pictures can as in this case be tiny and hard to read.

Please edit to include results from terminal for mokutil --sb

In terminal sudo dkms install rtl812au/5.6.4.2_35491.20191025 then reboot.  What is wrong with the internal Intel wifi?

I suspect your TP-LINK ARCHER T2U PLUS [RTL8821AU] driver is not working for the new kernel. (I note the dkms reports the driver as RTL8812au. is this right? The numbers don't match.)
Try the driver here. I think yours is on this. (8812au and 8821au)?
https://github.com/morrownr
Compatible Kernels
Kernels: 5.4 - 5.11 (Realtek)
Kernels: 5.12 - 6.10 (community support)

Use dkms status to identify the device driver (RTL8821AU) for each succesfully built kernel. Your original driver source could/will have an uninstall to uninstall it. If not then you could uninstall it as follows: -
Typical output of dkms status
rtl8821au/5.12.5.2, 6.8.0-41-generic, x86_64: installed
rtl8821au/5.12.5.2, 6.8.0-44-generic, x86_64: installed

Typical removal from the dkms. If it is removed it should also stop the driver installing but you might have to reboot to achieve this. You need to use your details of the driver you have installed but here are are some examples.
dkms remove rtl8812au/x.x.x.x --all
dkms remove rtl8812au/x.x.x.x -k  6.8.0-44-generic -a x86_64

Installation
Open a gnome-terminal
sudo apt install -y build-essential dkms git iw  #Tools needed
mkdir -p ~/src   #make a directory to place the sources
cd ~/src   #move to directory
git clone https://github.com/morrownr/8821au-20210708.git #download sources
cd ~/src/8821au-20210708  #Move into sources
sudo ./install-driver.sh #(Note to remove it run remove-driver.sh).
If you are running secure boot and you have not installed a mokkey the driver will not get signed so it will not run. The instructions on the site do give some advice regarding this.
I think it is a good idea to reboot before you starting testing.
I use this particular driver and it appears to work with 6.8.0-44-generic x86_64

Not really an answer. Where are the steps to remove the existing driver? You make comets like you think and probable which are comments you make in comments not in answers.
