RealTek Wifi adapter not working in 24.04.1
Same problem, different Ubuntu Version Mate desktop. Recently upgraded to 24.04
Following the instructions @chili555 gave in this Discussion: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150319/discussion-between-chili555-and-jim-hitek
Installed git, ran it, followed the instructions, upgrades and installs all worked. I now show the RealTek adapter in the network drop down.
However, all the entries for it are grayed out so I'm not able to use it.
What is the trick to re-activate this Wifi adapter? The RaLink adapter works fine.
Thanks.
@chili555 would you let me know what I did wrong?
*-network:1
description: Wireless interface
physical id: 4
bus info: usb@3:2
logical name: wlx003c81882098
serial: 00:3c:81:88:20:98
capabilities: ethernet physical wireless
configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtl8821au driverversion=v5.12.5.2-0-g70054197b.20210708 firmware=42.4 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=unassociated
EDIT: dkms status
rtl8821au/5.12.5.2, 6.8.0-49-generic, x86_64: installed
EDIT: FOUND the problem. The wifi adapter 'requires' the small inline booster module (which came with the adapter and that I'd forgotten about) to be attached (it has male-female USB connectors) to the adapter to function for some reason. Must have coding to communicate with the PC. So, it was basically Pilot Error by the IBTK.
Thanks for everyone's help.
`

That build for rtl8821au (v5.12.5-0...) looks old. Take a look at the answer here https://askubuntu.com/questions/1524610/tp-link-archer-t2u-plus-driver-issue-on-ubuntu-22-04-and-kernel-6-8-0-40-generic/1524681#1524681 and here (including install instructions)  https://askubuntu.com/questions/1526641/tp-link-ac-600-not-working/1526649#1526649 to install a more recent one.

The links just have me repeat what I've already done. I did use the latest download for the 20210708 code. At least that's the one the terminal line refers to: git clone https://github.com/morrownr/8821au-20210708.git

Followed the instructions again...downloaded a fresh copy of the 20210708 firmware, and still no change. The Realtek adapter is shown in the networking drop down from the task bar (panel in Mate), but all the selections are grayed out and non-functional. I did boot into Gnome and the same there. Gnome shows a Wifi Off/On key for the Realtek and it was ON. But, same issue there, would not attach.

Did you reboot after install? Append to your question the output of commend line 'dkms status'  'lsusb'  'lsmod | grep 8821' 'uname -r'

Try the following commands: 'sudo rfkill list' 'sudo rfkill unblock all' Stop network services: 'sudo systemctl stop NetworkManager.service';  Edit the following file 'sudo vim /var/lib/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.state' and check if 'WirelessEnabled=false' if it is change it to 'WirelessEnabled=true' and then restart the network services: 'sudo systemctl start NetworkManager.service'

@David: I always reboot. Tried the commands you listed and I use Nano for editing but when I type the line you show above, it shows =true;=true;=true.
